# know GMT difference

Tags: python, pytz

I have following code

```
ktm = timezone('Asia/Katmandu')
```

If I want to know zone of ktm, I can do like

```
ktm.zone
```

I know, Kathmandu is GMP+5:45. Is there any way to get this difference in pytz.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pytz
import datetime as dt
ktm = pytz.timezone('Asia/Katmandu')
utc = pytz.utc
now = dt.datetime.now()

now_utc = utc.localize(now)
now_ktm = now_utc.astimezone(ktm)

diff = now_ktm.replace(tzinfo=None) - now_utc.replace(tzinfo=None) 
print(diff)
5:45:00
```

There is also:

```
print(now_ktm.strftime('%z'))
# +0545
```

though this gives the difference as a string.

Comment: Thanks, This worked, but I was looking if there any inbuilt function with pytz.